# Java in Gnu/linux servers

Tags: linux, java

What is the use of installing java in linux server.
I have seen initialising java paths in `.bashrc` and using them in different scripts. What does this all mean.please help.

Dont have much knowledge of this, what I know is we have a Gun/linux server and java installed on it and I can see in `.bashrc` its initialisation. So what is this all for. What is the use of java here? Seems m nt[this word is unclear] explaining properly but would appreciate whatever info you can provide on this.

Comment: You need "a java server" in order to run java applications. Your question needs clarification, is something not working? Do you need to change anything?

Comment: Add the relevant sections of `.bashrc` to your question

Comment: `java` is used to run `java` programs. Maybe the server has some of its programs written in `java`. This is not uncommon.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty of applications on servers and workstations need Java for practical reasons.  Examples include the NetBackup GUI, LDAP client adminstration tools, Mathematical analysis packages, etc, while certainly not being limited to this short list.  A system is certainly more than just its kernel, as is implied by the "Gnu/linux" statement in your question.  I certainly wouldn't uninstall or remove it from my system just to be pedantic, unless you know for certain that you do not want it there.